# get song from folder android

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm using code below to get all songs from folder, but it's not working because it will only work with such paths: /sdcard/test.mp3, but i need to get songs from folder- eg /sdcard/
How can i do this without getting all songs?

```
 public Playlist getSongsByPath(String name){

        String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
                + "=?";

        String whereVal[] = { name };

        String orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
        Uri media = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(media, Song.FILLED_PROJECTION, where, whereVal, orderBy);

        Playlist result = new Playlist();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            result.addSong(new Song(cursor));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `File musicDirectory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC))` is what you are looking for? The music directory ?

Comment: no, i have a scanner which is searching for all folders with music on device's file system, then i want to get songs by folder. I'm using MediaStore

Comment: Good question...I am always using direct path address such as "/asset/bılabıla.mp3". I don't know your question's answer but you can try a loop for reading files until finding a good answer. Also your files' names should be like same beginning word. For instance; soundfile001,soundfile002... I hope you will find an answer.Greeting

Comment: i know bad solution - get all songs and then add to playlist only songs with specific path, but it's too slow

Answer (score -1):

By using the Mediastore, you will find all music on your device. The media scanning process maintains the android music database. The _DATA attribute holds the fully qualified pathname so could have differing paths. Eg /mnt/sdcard, /sdcard or wherever you have placed your music etc.
If you want to search the filesystem then mediastore is probably not the correct way to do it.
Ps. Your question is a little confusing? Perhaps you mean something else than "get songs from folder eg /sdcard/"